# Tkinter OptionMenu cant use .get in a function

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu, tkinter.optionmenu

I'm writing some code and i need a variable to change when the optionMenu is changed here is some of my code below

```
#!/user
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import locale
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.title("My Tax Calculator")
root.geometry("700x225")

def getStudentLoan():
    global StudentLoan
    StudentLoan = StudentLoanLi.get()

LeftFrame = Tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=200, pady=3)

Placeholder2 = Tk.Label(LeftFrame, text="")
Placeholder2.grid(row=2, column=1)

StudentLoanOp = Tk.StringVar()
StudentLoanOp.set("No")

StudentLoanLi = Tk.OptionMenu(Placeholder2, StudentLoanOp, "No", "Plan 1", "Plan 2", command=lambda _: getStudentLoan())
StudentLoanLi.grid(row=2, column=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

This will not work in pycharm editor i get this error "unresolved attribute reference error on 'get' for Class 'OptionMenu'"

and when i execute the code and try and change the OptionMenu i get this error in the console

"StudentLoan = StudentLoanLi.get()
AttributeError: OptionMenu instance has no attribute 'get'"

any help will greatly appreciated

Comment: The code you posted creates an empty window. Could you fix that so we can actually see the OptionMenu?

Comment: You should call `.get()` on the StringVar that actually holds the selected item, NOT the OptionMenu itself.

Comment: And to see the optionmenu, simply change the first argument to root `StudentLoanLi = Tk.OptionMenu(root, StudentLoanOp, ...)`

Comment: What is this lambda _ (underscore):  in

StudentLoanLi = Tk.OptionMenu(Placeholder2, StudentLoanOp, "No", "Plan 1", "Plan 2", command=lambda _: getStudentLoan())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OptionMenu` class has no `get` method. The correct way to get the selected item from an OptionMenu is to use the `get` method of the OptionMenu's `StringVar`, which you named `StudentLoanOp`:

```
def getStudentLoan():
    global StudentLoan
    StudentLoan = StudentLoanOp.get()
```

Comment: Thank you i feel like a total idiot i new this was the way just got confused with variable i was supposed to put .get